# SFMCSDK breaking Xcode previews in Xcode 14

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, xcode

We are using the marketing cloud SDK (through SPM) configured as mentioned in https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-migration.html

When using Xcode Version 14.0.1 (14A400) we get the following error with Xcode previews:

```
HumanReadableSwiftError

SettingsError: noExecutablePath(<IDESwiftPackageStaticLibraryProductBuildable:ObjectIdentifier(0x0000600017ec9e30):'SFMCSDK'>)
```

Googling around I found some people had a similar issue with AppCenter https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/707569 and other sdk.

The solution in the case of AppCenter was https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter-sdk-apple/issues/2429

But the `Package.swift` file doesn't contain the `type: .static` declaration, which was their solution.

Is this something the iOS provider of the package is aware?
Do they have a fix/workaround for this?

Right now SFMCSDK is preventing us to adopt Xcode 14, so it would be nice to get a solution to this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Package.Swift for SFMCSDK does not hardcode the type as ".static". This is an issue with Xcode IDE itself. Xcode version 14.1 beta 3 seems to have addressed this issue, we may have to wait for Xcode 14.1 official release.

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: I can confirm it works on Xcode 14.1 beta 3. Thanks